# Calculating and storing results of differences between rows in a dataframe based on a column value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and learning basic stuff. I have a dataframe in R with columns like controller_id, user_id, mth_id, col_val1 till col_val100.

```
df <- data.frame('controller_id' = c('X','X','X','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Z','Z'),
'user_id'=c('A','B','C','A','B','C','P','Q','R','P','Q','R',NA,NA),
'mth_id'=c('1393','1393','1393','1398','1398','1398','1393','1393','1393','1398','1398','1398','1393','1398'),
'col_val1' = c(5,4,6,3,1,10,12,15,18,13,19,1,5,2),
'col_val2'=c(8,12,9,2,12,5,7,9,11,4,0,7,10,5))

> df
   controller_id user_id mth_id col_val1 col_val2
1              X       A   1393        5        8
2              X       B   1393        4       12
3              X       C   1393        6        9
4              X       A   1398        3        2
5              X       B   1398        1       12
6              X       C   1398       10        5
7              Y       P   1393       12        7
8              Y       Q   1393       15        9
9              Y       R   1393       18       11
10             Y       P   1398       13        4
11             Y       Q   1398       19        0
12             Y       R   1398        1        7
13             Z    <NA>   1393        5       10
14             Z    <NA>   1398        2        5
```

What I want is to calculate the difference in col_values for each controller_id based on specific user_id, mth_id and display only those col_values which have decreased as the mth_id have increased.

For eg: for controller_id = X, we have 3 user_id as A,B,C for two different mth_ids. Code should calculate differences between col_val1 for mth_id 1398 and 1393 for all 3 users_id and if that difference is < 0 then I want an output like

```
Col_val1 for controller_id 'X', user_id 'A' has decreased from 5 to 3
```

If for a given controller_id there is no user_id associated then it should calculate the column value difference between controller_id itself.

Ideally, I want to store these output in a list/dataframe for later use. 
Also, the code is to run for approx. 900 columns present in the dataframe.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @akrun do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a base R solution using running group sums. And to iterate across all columns, use an `sapply()` passing in column names:

```
rowdiff <- function(col) {
             sapply(1:nrow(df),
               function(i){
                 # CONDITIONAL TO RETURN NA FOR FIRST VAL IN EACH USER ID
                 ifelse(sum(df[1:i, c("user_id")] == df$user_id[i]) == 1, NA,
                    # DIFFERENCE OF CURRENT LOOP COL VALUE - LAST COL VALUE OF USER ID GROUP
                    df[[col]][i] -
                    sum((df[1:i-1, c("user_id")] == df$user_id[i]) 
                    * df[1:i-1,][[col]]))
               })
           }


finaldf <- cbind(df, data.frame(sapply(names(df[c(3:ncol(df))]), rowdiff)))

#   user_id mth_id col_val1 col_val2 col_val3 col_val1 col_val2 col_val3
# 1       A   1398        4        2       12       NA       NA       NA
# 2       B   1398        3        3       30       NA       NA       NA
# 3       C   1398        1        1       14       NA       NA       NA
# 4       A   1393        5        7        7        1        5       -5
# 5       B   1393        2        6       18       -1        3      -12
# 6       C   1393        7        0        9        6       -1       -5
# 7       D   1398        4        5       12       NA       NA       NA
# 8       D   1393        0        3       24       -4       -2       12
```

And should you need statements written out:

```
statements <- function(col) {
  sapply(1:nrow(df),
         function(i){

           delta <- df[[col]][i]-
                      sum((df[1:i-1, c("controller_id")] == df$controller_id[i])
                         *(df[1:i-1, c("user_id")] == df$user_id[i]) 
                         * df[1:i-1,][[col]])

           changeword <- ifelse(delta < 0, "decreased", 
                                ifelse(delta > 0, "increased", "not changed"))

           ifelse(sum(df[1:i, c("user_id")] == df$user_id[i]) == 1, NA,
                  paste0(col, " for controller_id '", df$controller_id[i], "', user_id '", 
                         df$user_id[i], "' has ", changeword, " from ",
                         sum((df[1:i-1, c("controller_id")] == df$controller_id[i])
                             * (df[1:i-1, c("user_id")] == df$user_id[i]) 
                             * df[1:i-1,][[col]]), " to ",
                         df[[col]][i])

           )
         })
}
finaldf <- cbind(df, data.frame(sapply(names(df[c(4:ncol(df))]), statements)))
```

Output

```
                                                                  col_val1
1                                                                     <NA>
2                                                                     <NA>
3                                                                     <NA>
4    col_val1 for controller_id 'X', user_id 'A' has decreased from 5 to 3
5    col_val1 for controller_id 'X', user_id 'B' has decreased from 4 to 1
6   col_val1 for controller_id 'X', user_id 'C' has increased from 6 to 10
7                                                                     <NA>
8                                                                     <NA>
9                                                                     <NA>
10 col_val1 for controller_id 'Y', user_id 'P' has increased from 12 to 13
11 col_val1 for controller_id 'Y', user_id 'Q' has increased from 15 to 19
12  col_val1 for controller_id 'Y', user_id 'R' has decreased from 18 to 1
13                                                                    <NA>
14                                                                    <NA>
                                                                    col_val2
1                                                                       <NA>
2                                                                       <NA>
3                                                                       <NA>
4      col_val2 for controller_id 'X', user_id 'A' has decreased from 8 to 2
5  col_val2 for controller_id 'X', user_id 'B' has not changed from 12 to 12
6      col_val2 for controller_id 'X', user_id 'C' has decreased from 9 to 5
7                                                                       <NA>
8                                                                       <NA>
9                                                                       <NA>
10     col_val2 for controller_id 'Y', user_id 'P' has decreased from 7 to 4
11     col_val2 for controller_id 'Y', user_id 'Q' has decreased from 9 to 0
12    col_val2 for controller_id 'Y', user_id 'R' has decreased from 11 to 7
13                                                                      <NA>
14                                                                      <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks @Parfait for your response. It was helpful. However, my problem statement got a slight modification. I got one more hierarchical level to pick from. Can you suggest any changes that can solve this problem now?

Comment: Hey  @Parfait what if there has been no change in value. Since our delta is either increased or decreased, if a condition comes like there has been no change in value and I want to print it out. Any suggestions how that can be done.

Comment: See update, handling both the hierarchical `controller_id` and the *not increased* scenario. Always be sure to order dataframe by `mth_id` so 1393s come before 1398s.